# Symfony route with "#" sign (hash sign)

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, url-routing

I'm suing Symfony 1.4 and having issues adding a route that has a "#" (hash) sign

I want the route to be for example :

```
mydomain.com/#example
```

And it should lead to :

```
module : example
action : index
```

How should I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System):

```
<?php echo link_to('my article', 'article/read', array(
  'query_string' => 'title=Finance_in_France',
  'anchor' => 'foo'
)) ?>
=> <a href="/article/read?title=Finance_in_France#foo">my article</a>

<?php echo link_to('my article', 'article/read?title=Finance_in_France#foo') ?>
=> <a href="/routed/url/to/Finance_in_France#foo">my article</a>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I need the url /#example to go to a specific module within my project...

Comment: Anchors (#) can be used to navigate within a page, those are not sent back to the server so you can't use them in routes. Although some javascript frameworks use this hash fragments to provide permalinks for pages loaded by ajax.